# Disassembly view while debugging in Clion 2017.3.4 - what does it mean?

Tags: c, debugging, clion, disassembly

I'm currently using Clion 2017.3.4 in C99.

while trying to run and debug my program, the debugger jumps into 'disassembly view', and I want to know what the problem is.

basically, the function gets a season(type), a input string (season_info), and an index, that points to a different place in the input string.

the function should return the year as an **integer**, while the input is a string

the disassembly view is showen when I step into the free() line.
any ideas what the problem is? 
and generally what the disassembly view means?

```
int GetSeasonYear(Season season, const char* season_info, int *index){ 

char* tmp_str = GetStringByLine(season_info, index);
if(tmp_str == NULL){
    SeasonDestroy(season);
    return 0;
}

season->season_year = atoi(tmp_str);
free(tmp_str);

return 1;
```

}

this is the function used inside the GetSeasonYear function(although I check and it works fine).

```
char* GetStringByLine(const char* season_info, int* index){ // change back to static

int i = 0;

while(season_info[i] != '\n'){
    i++;
}

char* tmp_str = malloc(sizeof(char)*(i+1));
if(tmp_str == NULL){
    return NULL;
}

memcpy(tmp_str, season_info, sizeof(char)*i);
tmp_str[i+1]='\0';

*index = i;

return tmp_str;
```

}

thanks

Comment: The disassembly view simply shows assembly code corresponding to the instructions created by the compiler. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3cwf295.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stepping into a function (free) for which you either 
a) Do not have the source for 
or
b) have the source for but the debuuger cannot locate it.

Answer (score 0):

free() is a call to the system to release memory. It's more than likely been compiled with high optimisation and without debug symbols, so the best the debugger can do is just show you the disassembled machine code that it's executing.
Basically, it's normal. There's also very little benefit to stepping into calls like that.